# Change DB server at runtime

Tags: vb.net, subsonic, subsonic2.2

I have a large `vb.net` project running on `subsonic 2.2`.

I am looking for a way to change the connection string for `subsonic` at run-time, based on a separate configuration file. (basically connect with the sever information in my own configuration file.)

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have a configuration file with the correct server information. The information is available to me at runtime. I'm just not sure exactly how to change the server it is loading from.

Comment: I mean, before asking a question in StackOverflow, you're supposed to search, read tutorials and articles and other questions and try hard, and if you could not solve the problem, then show us your code here, and explain the problem in more detail to get better help.

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start with it. I need to mostly find the jumping off point where subsonic connects to the database, so I can change the value its using.

Comment: may be a related question here (although subsonic 3): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881626/how-do-you-change-subsonic-3s-connection-string-on-the-fly